# Cakephp 4 input control statment: $this->Form->control

Tags: cakephp-4.x

in cakephp 4 there is a statement/method like

`$this->Form->control('address_id',['options' => $addresstypes...]....`

which mainly works fine. I my case I would
like to  change the label of an select box to an external link.

Now safe, but in this case unfortunate adding the option:

`'label' => '<a href="whatever">whatever</a>'`

renders my link useless because due to safety reasons it translates to:

`&lt;a href="whatever"&gt;whatever&lt;/a&gt;`

Obvious is also that this is a nice feature except you want to turn a label into a link.

Anybody an idea? Otherwise I have to rewrite a couple of hundreds of
`$this->Form->control...`

statements.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find it explicitly documented for the label attribute, but if you add `'escape' => false` to your options in such cases, that should take care of it.

Comment: Thx, sometimes life can be so easy :-)